# PHP Array within an Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
  $row[];  // Declare array. PRETEND ITS AN ARRAY
  $row2[]; // Declare another
  $row3[]; // Declare one more

  $rowarray[];

  $rowarray[0] = $row
  $rowarray[1] = $row2
  $rowarray[2] = $row3 // Store array in an array
```

My Questions:
 1. Is this valid or even useful?
 2. If I do this, how do I access $row[0] $row[1] etc.

Comment: There is no point to declaring array sizes in php. Arrays automatically size to the elements stored in the array.

Comment: All those statements "declaring" an array are **not** declaring an array.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. BUT do you know the answer to my question.

Comment: AFAIK, $row[3] will try to find the third index in the array $row

Comment: Ok. I understand.. I couldn't use actually code to illustrate my question, but anyway.. Does anyone know the answer to my question?

Comment: Yes, it's a multidimensional array and they're used quite often in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The concept is valid, but the syntax is not -- arrays are not explicitly declared like that in PHP. A correct way to initialize this would be something like:

   ```
   $row1 = array(1, 2, 3);
   $row2 = array(4, 5, 6);
   $row3 = array(7, 8, 9);
   $rowarray = array($row1, $row2, $row3);
   ```

   Or, equivalently and more succinctly:

   ```
   $rowarray = array(
       array(1, 2, 3),
       array(4, 5, 6),
       array(7, 8, 9)
   );
   ```
2. `$rowarray[1][2]`. Indexes are in order, so, given the example data I used, this would be 6 (element 2 of the array which is element 1 of `$rowarray`).

Comment: Or even more succinctly, `$rowarray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` :)

Comment: @NullUserException: If you're using PHP 5.4 or later, yes.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Multi-dimensional array.

For example:

```
$a1 = array(
   array(1, 2, 3, 4),
   array(1, 2, 3, 4)
);
```